# Is Torah considered Din el Batel (دين البطل)?

Tags: torah

Is Torah (sharia'a of Jew) considered Din el Batel (دين البطل)?

Comment: Idk what دين البطل means. But, anything other than Islam is wrong. And we would not say the Torah is wrong because we say proper understanding of the true Torah entails following Islam.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, please see my answer below regardless of the votes.

Answer (score 4):

دين الباطل means a false or wrong religion.

The Torah is a divine scripture, and can not be called a false religion, rather the Quran says about it:

> إنا أنزلنا التوراة فيها هدى ونور يحكم بها النبيون الذين أسلموا للذين هادوا والربانيون والأحبار بما استحفظوا من كتاب الله وكانوا عليه شهداء
>
> Indeed, We sent down the Torah, in which was guidance and light. The prophets who submitted [to Allah] judged by it for the Jews, as did the rabbis and scholars by that with which they were entrusted of the Scripture of Allah, and they were witnesses thereto.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:44](https://quran.com/5/44?translations=20)</sup>

> ولقد آتينا موسى الكتاب من بعد ما أهلكنا القرون الأولى بصائر للناس وهدى ورحمة لعلهم يتذكرون
>
> And We gave Moses the Scripture, after We had destroyed the former generations, as enlightenment for the people and guidance and mercy that they might be reminded.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 28:43](https://quran.com/28/43?translations=20)</sup>

The only issue with the Torah is that the people have distorted its interpretation and text.

Judaism (the creed and shariah of the Jews of our times) is a false religion. That is because it denies the prophets such as Jesus عليه السلام and Muhammad ﷺ, and it denies the Quran. And it has many other false beliefs and innovations. Nothing is acceptable from anyone now except to follow the religion of Islam:

> ومن يبتغ غير الإسلام دينا فلن يقبل منه وهو في الآخرة من الخاسرين
>
> And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:85](https://quran.com/3/85)</sup>

> لا يسمع بي أحد من هذه الأمة يهودي ولا نصراني ثم لم يؤمن بالذي أرسلت به إلا كان من أصحاب النار
>
> Whoever amongst the community of Jews or Christians hears about me, but does not affirm his belief in that with which I have been sent and dies in this state, he shall be but one of the denizens of Hell-Fire.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:153)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add the following rather short remarks to the existing posts (as they already include some details).

1. > دين البَطَل

Doesn't make any sense in Arabic as it literally means:

> religion the hero or the hero religion

What you are meaning to say is either:

> دين باطِلٌ

meaning a "wrong, false,void... religion" or:

> الدين الباطِلٌ

meaning "**the** wrong, false, void ... religion".

or and this is less used, as it doesn't fit well:

> دين بُطْل *or*
> الدين البُطْل

which could be interpreted as "(the) religion of lies".

2. **The Torah is one of the revelations of Allah so it can't be a leading to a wrong religion**, even if -we as Muslims- believe that the original version was distorted (or at least it meaning/interpretation was distorted).
   For this reason saying the "Torah is a wrong religion" is not appropriate.
3. **The Torah similarly to the qur'an is a source of the Jewish shar'ia or Allah's shari'a in the original form**, understanding and interpretation as it was taught by Allah's messengers() and prophets() who were sent to bani Israel (not exclusively).
4. **From Muslim perspective both Judaism and Christianity became void by the revelation of the qur'an** as both are asked therein to follow it, and similarly in their own revelation, they are asked to follow a messenger (often referred to as the Messiahs). Nevertheless some scholars say that whatever the qur'an has made void, by its revelation is void, but what is not remains applicable by Muslims. This view would for example support the fact of punishment of adulterers by stoning.
   Therefore it is safer to say: Christianity and Judaism are void religions.

Answer (score 1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**Hello,**

I hope you are doing well. Thank you for asking your question. I am assuming you meant to say religion of falsehood. However, the Torah in its original form is one of the holy books. It came to Prophet Moses (peace be upon him). Then later Prophet Jesus (peace be upon him) was sent to have the people come back to the straight path. However, the jews did not believe in him and the group that did, altered his status and went against his original teachings.

> Then the factions differed [concerning Jesus] from among them, so woe to those who disbelieved - from the scene of a tremendous Day. (Quraan chapter 19 verse 37)

> And [for] their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah." And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him; but [another] was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they did not kill him, for certain. (Quraan chapter 4 verse 157)

> And there is none from the People of the Scripture but that he will surely believe in him [i.e., Jesus] before his death.1 And on the Day of Resurrection he will be against them a witness. (Quraan chapter 4 verse 159)

When the Quraan came it came as truth to differentiate and clear the matter what the people had distorted. It gave respect to the Prophets (peace be upon them all), gave instructions as to the purpose of life and much more.

At the end of the day the Quraan says

> Abraham was neither a Jew nor a Christian, but he was one inclining toward truth, a Muslim [submitting to Allah]. And he was not of the polytheists. (Quraan chapter 3 verse 67)

**Conclusion**

Any prior teachings were overwritten when the Quraan came. It gives instructions on how to live your life, describes past events that had occurred, differentiates right and wrong, etc.

**Have a Nice Day!**

Comment: "However when Prophet Jesus (peace be upon him) came then the clear differentiations began." ... This statement is factually incorrect. The Jews had gone astray way before the time of Prophet Jesus (Isa) and Prophet John (Yahya) .. They had committed many sins and killed a number of Prophets in the period between Moses & Jesus. The Quran speaks on this on several occasions.

Comment: @Ahmed, As Salaamu 3laykum, jazakaALLAH khairan for that clarification. I will revise that sentence.